# Change spell check dictionary in Sublime Text 2

Tags: spell-check, sublime-text-2

Is there a dictionary of technical/computer/internet words to supplement Sublime Text 2's default dictionary? For example, words such as "blog", "online", "wifi" are all considered misspelled given the default [Hunspell](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/spell_checking.html) dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The only openoffice dictionary extensions I know of that fall into the "technical" realm are the [chemistry](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/ChemDictOOo) and [medical](http://www.e-medtools.com/openmedspel.html) extensions.  I do not believe there exists exactly what you are looking for, however.